# Will Apple review my app only with sign-in button without registration button? [2023]

Tags: ios, review

Can I create an mobile app wihout registration button, but only with sign-in button. I would like to have additional feauters only for users who created an account on my website.

Is it still possible in 2023?

Comment: AFAIK it's possible, you also need to provide an account with full access to your app, and avoid [Minimum Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)